# SQLite like query for multiple rows

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I have the following table

```
---------------------------------------
id,     type,     keyword,     default
---------------------------------------
1,      1,        mcdonalds,       1
2       1,        food,            0
3,      1,        drinks,          0
4,      2,        vending machine, 1
5,      2,        drinks,          0
6,      3,        station,         1
7,      3,        travel,          0
8       3,        train,           0
```

The idea behind this is that I want a serach query returing 'a unique' type for keywords (the default row), so when I search mcdonalds, I get the first row, but when I search food or drinks I allso get the first row.

I have done this using a subselect.

```
SELECT type, keyword FROM keywords WHERE type IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM keywords WHERE keyword like '%?%') AND `default`=1
;
```

This works like a charm, now however I want to be able to give multiple keywords, for example "drinks & food" I have tried

```
SELECT type, keyword FROM keywords WHERE type IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM keywords WHERE keyword like '%?%' OR keyword like'%?%') AND `default`=1
;
```

But then when I search for "food & drinks" in this case I would get both "the vending machine" and the "mcdonalds". However the vending machine only has an assosiated keyword "drinks" (it serves no food) So I don't want that one in my results.

When I do 'AND' instead of OR like, I get no results at all (since one row cant have both values at the same time).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two independent subqueries, then combine the lookups with `AND`:

```
SELECT type,
       keyword
FROM keywords
WHERE type IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM keywords WHERE keyword like '%drinks%')
  AND type IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM keywords WHERE keyword like '%food%')
  AND "default"=1
```

Comment: your query also always return one record and if add 3 keyword `AND type IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM keywords WHERE keyword like '%station%')` it returns nothing

Comment: It will return two records if there are two types where both keywords match.

Comment: Yeah, this works kinda, but is not what I am looking for, when I now look for something like "e d" it will show like everything because the  like is too greedy.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
t = keywords
*/

SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE type IN (
    SELECT type
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_matches,
            type
        FROM t
        WHERE keyword LIKE '%drinks%'
        OR  keyword   LIKE '%food%'
        GROUP BY type
        )
        q
    ORDER BY count_matches DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    )
AND "default" = 1
```

Comment: This always returns one record, even if the keywords match two or zero types.

Comment: Based on question, need to return default keyword with best maximum matches

Comment: Your query indeed returns one type with the most matches, but this is not how I've interpreted the question ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for all your help. It has been figured out! :)

```
 SELECT type, keyword FROM keywords WHERE type IN 
 (SELECT type FROM keywords WHERE (`keyword` LIKE '%drinks%' OR keyword like '%food%') AND `default`!= 1 GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2)
 AND `default`=1
```

The query can be built dynamically so what this does is use COUNT. The number of rows for count returned in the subquery must be at least as much as the number of keywords the user entered.

[b]edit does not seem to work, the or and like sometimes gives an higher count than expected[/b]